# DocumentDB vs. SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sql-database, nosql

I have a question regarding the usage of a DocumentDB or SQL-Database.
E.g. I have categories which can have multiple child categories and so on. Every category can have multiple attributes and every attribute can have one or many values. Would it be better to use a schemaless solution like a DocumentDB because I could add new sub categories etc. with no effort or is it better to stick with a schema and use a SQL-Database.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's really no right answer to this. Only opinions, on a rather broad topic. Which database type, and engine, you choose will really be up to your app, your skill set, your reporting needs, etc.

Comment: I have a blog post and benchmark around this here: https://koukia.ca/azure-documentdb-vs-sql-azure-performance-comparison-revised-178a90038146

Answer (score 3):

As @DavidMakogon said, there is not a standard & absolute right answer, it just up to you and up to application scenario. For this current needs to store a tree structure of categories with attributes, it's simple to design database schema & develop application for both without any addition condition like data volume and concurrency, etc, and both are good.

Consideration for others, there are two documents may help analyzing the features which you may need to use in your application or more suitable for your scenario, to make your choice.

1. [MongoDB vs MySQL: Comparison Between RDBMS and Document Oriented Database](https://blog.udemy.com/mongodb-vs-mysql/), it's very similar for comparision between DocumentDB and SQL Database.
2. [10 things never to do with a relational database](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2616126/application-development/10-things-never-to-do-with-a-relational-database.html), I think the advantage of RDBMS is as well known and be suitable for which scenario, but NoSQL's not.

Hope it helps.